# Spring batch restart job failing with transaction exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-transactions, spring-batch-tasklet

I'm testing my spring batch job with `restart` feature, I'm processing total of nine records with `chunk size 5,` after processing the first chunk - I'm intentionally failing the second chunk to test the failure scenario. As expected, my batch got failed after the first chunk processed successfully and in my table - `batch_job_execution` I've the record with execution id and status as `FAILED`. Now I'm running the restart job by passing the execution id to verify the failed records are processing or not. But I'm getting the below exception when I run the failed job:

```
2022-05-03 18:58:44,829 [ JOB=scheduler.id_IS_UNDEFINED ] [THREAD=main] ERROR [RestartJobTasklet] 
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).while restart the failed job executionId8
```

Could you please assist me here - what I'm missing here. Please find my code below:

Appreciated your help in advance!

**TestJobConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Profile("myJob-config")
public class TestJobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MyItemWriter myItemWriter;

    @Autowired
    private RestartJobTasklet restartJobTasklet;


    @Bean("myJob-config")
    public Job job(@Qualifier("validateStep") Step validateStep,
                   @Qualifier("processRecords") Step processRecords) {
        Job job = jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob-config")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(validateStep)
                .on("FAILED")
                .end()
                .from(validateStep).on("*").to(processRecords)
                .end()
                .build();
        return job;
    }

    @Bean("restart-myjob")
    public Job restartJob(@Qualifier("restartMyJobStep") Step restartMyJobStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("restart-myjob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(restartMyJobStep)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "restartMyJobStep")
    public Step restartMyJobStep() {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("restart-failed-job")
                .tasklet(restartJobTasklet)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "processRecords")
    public Step processRecords() {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("process-csv-records").<Employee, Employee>chunk(5)
                .reader(reader())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "validateStep")
    public Step validateStep(@Qualifier("validateTasklet") Tasklet validateTasklet) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("validateStep")
                .tasklet(validateTasklet)
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "validateTasklet")
    public Tasklet validateTasklet() {
        return new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Employee> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

        flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        flatFileItemReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/csv/emps.csv"));

        DefaultLineMapper<Employee> empDefaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"id", "firstName", "lastName"});

        empDefaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        empDefaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new EmployeeFieldSetMapper());
        empDefaultLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();

        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(empDefaultLineMapper);

        return flatFileItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter() {
        return myItemWriter;
    }
}
```

**RestartJobTasklet.java**

```
@Component
public class RestartJobTasklet implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

    @Autowired
    JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    @Autowired
    JobOperator jobOperator;
    private StepExecution stepExecution;
    private JobExecution jobExecution;
    @Autowired
    private OpsJobProperties props;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
        this.jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution,
                                ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        Long executionId = 8l;
        try {
            Long restartId = jobOperator.restart(executionId);
            JobExecution restartExecution = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(restartId);
        } catch (JobRestartException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw exception;
        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
}
```

**DBConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(@Autowired DataSource dataSource,
                                       @Autowired PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        jobRepositoryFactory.setDatabaseType(DatabaseType.POSTGRES.name());
        jobRepositoryFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jobRepositoryFactory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        jobRepositoryFactory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE");
        jobRepositoryFactory.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
        jobRepositoryFactory.setMaxVarCharLength(1000);
        jobRepositoryFactory.setValidateTransactionState(Boolean.FALSE);
        return jobRepositoryFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean()
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        PGSimpleDataSource pgSimpleDataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        pgSimpleDataSource.setServerName("my-db-server");
        pgSimpleDataSource.setDatabaseName("test-db");
        pgSimpleDataSource.setUser("test");
        pgSimpleDataSource.setPassword("test");
        return pgSimpleDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(final JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return postProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobOperator jobOperator(final JobLauncher jobLauncher, final JobRepository jobRepository,
                                   final JobRegistry jobRegistry, final JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
        final SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
        jobOperator.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
        jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
        return jobOperator;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExplorer jobExplorer(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        final JobExplorerFactoryBean bean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        bean.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
        bean.setJdbcOperations(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

}
```

**Error Log**

```
2022-05-03 18:58:44,865 [ JOB=scheduler.id_IS_UNDEFINED ] [THREAD=main] ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] 
Encountered an error executing step restart-failed-job in job restart-myjob
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:177)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator.restart(SimpleJobOperator.java:283)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$44ee6049.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5e87de1.restart(<generated>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to restart a job from within a tasklet in another job. This tasklet (`RestartJobTasklet`) is already running in a transaction, and calling a method that results in another transaction being created with `JobRepository#createJobExecution` down the line. Hence the error. In other words, you should not use the `JobRepository` in a transactional context.

I am not sure if it's a good idea to create a job to restart another job. Restarting a failed job instance is typically a technical task that does not require a job. I would recommend designing jobs to implement business logic, but not for technical tasks.

That said, if you extract the restart code in a `main` method, your sample should work as expected.